# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_or_insert'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datastore

I'm trying to create a simple python app with Google's datastore that stores emails for a newsletter without storing duplicate emails, but the code I have is throwing the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_or_insert'`
1. How do fix the error?
2. If the email does exist, and "subscribed"=false, how do I update it to True?

```
import webapp2
import json

from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Email(ndb.Model):
    subscribed = ndb.BooleanProperty()

    @staticmethod
    def create(email):
        ekey = ndb.Key("Email", email)
        entity = ndb.get_or_insert(ekey)
        if entity.subscribed:  ###
            # This email already exists
            return None
        entity.subscribed = True
        entity.put()
        return entity

class New(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        Email().create(self.request.get('email'))

        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'   
        obj = {
            'success': True
            }
        self.response.out.write(json.dumps(obj))


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    webapp2.Route(r'/parse', New),
], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_or_insert` is a method of the `ndb.Model` class, not of the `ndb` module, see [Class Methods](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Class_Methods).

So you may want to use

```
entity = ndb.Model.get_or_insert(ekey)
```

or even

```
entity = Email.get_or_insert(ekey)
```